# Adjustment of multiple test in contrasts of contrasts

Tags: r, multiple-comparisons

I have a model where I care about testing the differences among interaction terms.
To make is more straightforward, I just use lm

The model is :

`mdl<-lm(Ethylene ~ Genotype * Treatment,data=df)`

I can obviously get the model summary, including the interaction term compared to the reference.
What I want to get is the pairwise comparison of all of the interaction terms:
It is possible with emmeans library as:

```
library(emmeans)
emms_f<-emmeans(mdl, ~Genotype*Treatment)
contrast(emms_f, interaction = c( "pairwise","consec"))
```

To come to my question.
The result of the contrast for ref vs other is the same as the result of summary(mdl).
**However, there is no adjusting for multiple testing problem**. I can adjust simply just by adding *adjust="mvt"* (or other), but I can´t find anywhere the adjustment is being made.
Neither in the [vignette of emmeans](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/emmeans/vignettes/interactions.html), nor in any Q&A asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51818187/interaction-contrast-with-glmer), [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/355611/pairwise-comparisons-with-emmeans-for-a-mixed-three-way-interaction-in-a-linear), or some others, every answer omit the adjustment.
If I adjust, the result of course will not be consistent with the summary outcome, but I can't figure out why the adjustment is not needed in this case - or is it done somewhere where I don't see it?

Thank you for any explanation of why yes or why not.

Comment: how many genotypes, and how many treatments are there? If there is only two of each, then there is only one interaction contrast, and hence no multiplicity adjustment is needed or even possible.

Comment: There are 5 Genotypes and 2 Treatments - so I believe it is necessary

Comment: That is what is done now. If you don't specify an adjustment. none us made.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a demo that the software does apply the adjustment in another example, and annotates that fact.

```r
library(emmeans)

warp.lm = lm(breaks ~ wool * tension, data = warpbreaks)
warp.emm = emmeans(warp.lm, ~ wool * tension)
contrast(warp.emm, interaction = c("pairwise", "consec"), adjust = "mvt")
##  wool_pairwise tension_consec estimate   SE df t.ratio p.value
##  A - B         M - L             -21.1 7.29 48  -2.895  0.0108
##  A - B         H - M              10.6 7.29 48   1.447  0.2619
## 
## P value adjustment: mvt method for 2 tests
```

<sup>Created on 2022-10-04 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

But maybe I missed the point of the question. Is it "why is the *default* adjustment method `"none"`? I'm not sure how to answer that, but here are a few comments

1. Yes, it is true that
   the default adjustment method is `"none"`
   when `interaction` is specified.
2. When `interaction` is *not* specified, there is often
   a default adjustment method that is handed down as
   an attribute from the contrast method code specified
   in the `method` argument. For example, with
   `method = "pairwise"`, the default adjustment method
   is `"tukey"`.
3. When `interaction` *is* specified, then `contrast`
   is run multiple times, once for each factor involved.
   The associated contrast methods may recommend different
   adjustments, but even if they all say the same thing,
   that is often *not* helpful. For
   example, even if `"pairwise"` is used every time,
   the Tukey adjustment is *inappropriate* for the set
   of interaction contrasts, because we no longer have
   a single set of pairwise comparisons. So even if
   we *specify* that we want a Tukey adjustment, it will
   get overruled and changed to `"sidak"`.
4. It is generally unclear, at least to me, what should
   be the default adjustment method. I suppose an
   argument could be made for `"mvt"`, but I hesitate to make that the default because it is computationally
   costly, and it produces slightly different results
   each time because it is a randomized algorithm.
5. What do you think the default *should* be?

Comment: Thank you, My question was more like whether it is appropriate to adjust for multitesting when comparing pairwise interaction or not. 
As I think I should but it seems like nobody is doing so. Regarding to your 5th question, I would just not set up a default and make users always do it, then at least every time users need to think about it.